# why does the ball in the accelerometer example always start at 0,0?

Tags: android, flash, air, accelerometer

i've just started playing with the accelerometer in flash cs6, starting with the template: Air for Android > Accelerometer

its works just dandy, but no matter where i place the ball on the stage to begin with, the app opens up with the ball at 0,0.  (the ball then immediately snaps to within the stage because the code prevents it from going out.)

i dont see any code that would make the ball go to that location from its starting point.  the move code is like this:

```
function moveBall(evt:Event){
ball.x -= accelX*30;
ball.y += accelY*30;
}
```

so i would expect it to keep the starting point on the stage that i see in the timeline and start moving it FROM THERE based on the accelerometer.  anyone know why it doesnt do that?  same thing if i test on the device or in AIR debug launcher.  why oh why!?

Comment: Variables are usually initialized automatically with 0 (if they are initialized at all). That would happen implicitly if you just use a variable without ever giving it an explicit value in a lot of languages.

Comment: aright i think i figured it out.  the problem is that accelX and accelY start out as NaN when the app initializes, and thats whats making the ball move to 0,0.  the ball starts where i place it if i change the move code to something like:

Comment: if (!isNaN(accelX)) {
 ball.x -= accelX*30;
}
if (!isNaN(accelY)) {
 ball.y += accelY*30;
}